# The 1080 amalgamations of the tetragrammaton

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah, nefesh-hachaim, shemos-sacred-names

In the sefer Nefesh HaChaim Gate 1 Chapter 2 in the first gloss (hagah) the author explains that what is meant by God continually renewing the world is the constant reconstruction (amalgamation) of the shem Havayah (tetragrammaton) (and their nekudos) at the root/source of existence. 
Can someone explain this idea?

Comment: see vilna gaon lamed likutim sof sefer dtzniuta. says something interesting about time which i don't understand in the least.

Comment: [This page](http://vikikabballa.wiki.co.il/index.php/%D7%AA%D7%AA%D7%A8%22%D7%A3) mentions (in a somewhat terse fashion) various ways to count 1080 combinations of HaShem's name. More generally, this corresponds to the 1080 [*chalakim*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helek) in an hour.